# What term is used to mean a "yet-undiscovered, yet possibly out there civilization"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to refer to an unknown, elusive, undiscovered civilization? (e.g. perhaps it is buried in sands or hidden under some dense jungle, or buried under ocean).

This term might be similar to "John Doe", used to refer to an unnamed person, but "Planet X" is a similar analogy, referring to some yet as of undiscovered planet. I thought the word "Civilization X" might work, but I'm finding such few search results, as to not support this terminology.

Is there such a word in English?

Answer (score 1):

A common word for such a civilization is "Atlantean". The word derives from the legend of the lost city of Atlantis, a city that was described by Plato as having sunk beneath the waves of the Atlantic Ocean in early times (about ten thousand years ago). The inhabitants were variously supposed to have had an advanced constitutional civilization.

Why Plato imagined such a thing is unclear. A known history of rapid relative changes in Mediterranean sea and land levels that produced sudden coastal submergences and emergences would certainly have conditioned his mind in that direction. These changes originated, and still do, in volcanic or tectonic activity.

Comment: Can that word refer to one that is possibly genuine, just as of yet undiscovered civilization, not just a mythical one?

Comment: I believe that it could be so applied. The mythical nature of your undiscovered civilization applies until it is discovered, so the word still applies until discovery, after which I presume you you have a "discovered civilization".

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the word *uncontacted* as in *uncontacted civilisation*. Or perhaps *mythical*?

> **Uncontacted (adj):** (anthropology, of a tribal society) Completely isolated from other cultures.
>
>  [[Your Dictionary]](https://www.yourdictionary.com/uncontacted)

Also see [*uncontacted peoples*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontacted_peoples)

Comment: The problem with uncontacted is I'm not necessarily meaning it still has living people. It could be some real civilization that once existed, but knowledge of it was lost and its ruins not yet discovered.